# how to send DAILY email using python at Google App Engine

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine to deploy a very simple App which takes user's email and send them email daily (at the same time, say around 10 am).

I am using the schedule with the following code after user submit an email address:

```
class Submission (Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('submitted.html')
        schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(send_email)

        while True:
            print "The email is working"
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)
```

But when deploy this code, the page ("submitted.html") can never be loaded (maybe because the while loop I think).

I am new to programming, not really sure whether this makes sense. But generally, how to deploy a Python code which can keep running and send the regular email out?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: You should set up a cron job to run every day at 10am.  It would go through the datastore to find all the submission and email them. in `Submission()` you would write what you need to the datastore. 
 https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron